# Azure SDK Ruby Set Container ACL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

I'm using https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby in my Rails application. I need to set the container policy but I don't know how to create a Signed Identifier instance for the set_container_acl method.

The comments say to pass in an array of "Azure::Entity::SignedIdentifier instances" but when I try to create an instance I get "uninitialized constant Azure::Storage::Entity". Scoured the net/documentation can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around in the azure gem files I was able to find a signed identifier file in the service directory. It's not loaded with azure for some reason so you have to require it.

```
require 'azure'
require 'azure/service/signed_identifier'

def some_method
  # Some code here. Create blobs instance.
  # blobs = Azure::Blob::BlobService.new
  sas = Azure::Service::SignedIdentifier.new
  sas.id = identifier
  policy = sas.access_policy
  policy.start = (Time.now - 5 * 60).utc.iso8601
  policy.expiry = (Time.now + 1.years).utc.iso8601
  policy.permission = "r"
  identifiers = [sas]
  options = { timeout: 60, signed_identifiers: identifiers }
  container, signed = blobs.set_container_acl(container_name, "", options)
end
```